# Executing multiple database calls - single or multi threaded?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await

I am trying to understand which approach is the best to take when executing multiple database calls. I am having lots of screens that contain the same pattern:

- fetch the data asynchronously (async/await) on screen loading
- return control to UI thread so screen can be loaded
- at some point update UI when data arrived

Some screens have only one database call, and some screen have multiple database calls.

A typical database call

```
private Task<List<Product>> GetProductsAsync()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<List<Product>> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<Product>>();
        TaskEx.Run(() => tcs.SetResult(Repository.GetAllProducts()));
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

usage on screen with single call

```
// an event handler,can be marked as async void
public override async void OnActivated()
{
    base.OnActivated();
    ProductList = await GetProductsAsync();
}
```

usage on screen with multiple calls

```
// an event handler,can be marked as async void
public override async void OnActivated()
{
    base.OnActivated();
    ProductList = await GetProductsAsync();
    CustomerList = await GetCustomersAsync();
    OtherList = await GetOthersAsync();
}
```

As you can see, current implementation will spawn multiple threads from thread pool on screen with multiple calls. Is this a correct approach?

Another approach is to retrieve all data in one Task, but that would result in retrieving an array of lists in tcs.Result, which is kind of unclear what is being retrieved (from the point of code readability).

Do you thing that executing each database call in its own thread is correct approach, and if not what is your suggestion?

Comment: Your current implementation will not spawn multiple threads. It executed one by one as you are awaiting before calling next method.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel First call to products will spawn a new thread, since TaskEx.Run will get a new thread from thread pool. The same for second call, third, etc...

Comment: First call to products will spawn a new thread, but `await` will asynchronously wait till `GetProductsAsync` gets completed. Only then it will call `GetCustomersAsync`. So there are no need for multiple threads here. Same thread which finished the `GetProductsAsync` task can execute the `GetCustomersAsync` task and so forth. Did you see what I mean? If you need all the three to be done at the same time you need to start them same time and await all of them together with `await Task.WhenAll`

Comment: Are you sure that your database can deal with simultaneous queries? Multi threading would be more than pointless without that.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel This is not true, I have just tested it. a call to GetProducts executed on threadId=13, and GetCustomers executed on ThreadId=12. Only one query can e executed at a time, no simultaneous execution.

Comment: @Sheridan Queries are not executed simultaneously, but sequentially, but on a different thread than UI.

Comment: @Goran That's what am trying to say. I didn't say it will execute in single thread. Read my comment again. I said same thread *can execute* next task. My point is you are doing it one by one not all at one shot.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It is NOT the same thread, that is my point. Of course I am doing it one by one, but I am using TWO DIFFERENT threads, one after another. Ui ManagedThreadId=1, so that makes 3 threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `async-await` all calls may run on different threads, but not necessarily at the same time (concurrently). In your case all calls are sequential, so you're not hitting the DB concurrently.

About having concurrent calls to the DB, it depends on the db itself. Most databases can handle multiple calls concurrently, especially on different tables. It could however increase contention if the concurrent operations use the same locks. It could go either way, but in most cases concurrent calls to a database is a good thing.

---

About `GetProductsAsync` why are you using TaskCompletionSource instead of:

```
private Task<List<Product>> GetProductsAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() => Repository.GetAllProducts());
}
```

Comment: I already do not use concurrent calls, so I do not understand your advice? I am using EF DbContexr which does not support conccurent calls, but I did not specify what ORM I am using, since it is not important in this case. And I tried to avoid people suggesting to use new EF6 async feature, which I cannot use since I am using 4.0 framework, and EF6 async feature is supported only on 4.5+.

Comment: Regarding the part you added, yes, tsc is completely sufficient here. My qyestion was ore of, is it OK to spawn 5 different threads to get data, or should I wrap all calls into one tread. Or the overall performance is not impacted, and I should just go with the first one, which is more understandable.

Comment: @Goran You asked which is correct. Single or multi-threaded database calls. Both are correct, but concurrent calls may achieve better results. That's my answer.

Comment: @Goran Your code isn't multi-threaded, and you're not spawning 5 different threads. There's no reason to use TCS to create a task instead of just using the task you already have.

Comment: My code is multi-threaded, I am creating new thread each time TaskEx.Run() is executed. On Each Run() I get a new thread with different ManagedThreadId, so that means it is assigning different thread each time a different database call is issued. I have already commented on TCS...

Comment: @Goran 1. You are not creating a thread, you are using a thread pool thread. 2. If your database calls are not concurrent then you aren't using multiple threads, even if you're using a different thread each time. 3. Your comment was that "tsc is completely sufficient here", if tsc means TCS, then that comment is wrong. TCS is redundant, it doesn't add anything. You could also add an empty for loop and it would be as sufficient as a TCS.

Comment: Well,my bad, what I meant is insufficient, since I agreed with 'yes'. Care yo elaboreate about the difference between the creating a thread and using thread pool thread? Isn't that the same?

Comment: @Goran No. Creating a thread `new Thread()` is a very expensive operation. Getting a thread that was already created and just sits and waits for work from the thread pool is very "cheap". More about ThreadPools: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/173581